# PyQT5: how to add custom signal and slot?

Tags: python, pyqt5

i want to change slider position, when the `self.factor` is changed  during set_parameter(). More precisely, how to update slider position as the value changes during computation?

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSlider, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
class Params():
    def __init__(self):
        self.factor = 0

    def get_parameter(self):
            return self.factor
        
    def set_parameter(self, val):
            self.factor =val

class SliderWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, param: Params):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.params = param

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.slider = QSlider()
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_param_change)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.slider.setMinimum(4)
        self.slider.setMaximum(8)
    
    def on_param_change(self):
        value = self.params.get_parameter()
        self.slider.setValue(value)
        

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.params = Params()
        self.scene = SliderWidget(self.params)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scene)
        self.shortcutUp = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+W'), self)
        self.shortcutDw = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+S'), self)

        self.shortcutUp.activated.connect(self.up)
        self.shortcutDw.activated.connect(self.down)

    def up(self):
        print('up')
        value = (self.params.get_parameter() + 1)
        self.params.set_parameter(value)

    def down(self):
        print('down')
        value = (self.params.get_parameter() -1)
        self.params.set_parameter(value)

import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you tried QSlider.setValue? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#value-prop

Comment: Hi, yes slider.setvalue() is set, but my value is changing during computation, where main window is already running, as soon as my value changed i want to update slider position. Like, if I move slider, value will change right? Similarly if value changed slider should change it's position.

Comment: @user17502017 When you say "but my value is changing during computation", you mean inside a for-loop, or by briefly updating the value in the background, such as using a `QTimer`?

Comment: @carl HR, no I have a model, where vboxwidget is child widget of mainwindow where vbox has 4-8 slider. To increment slider value, I have created keyshortcut in mainwindow to increase value. Each time I pressed shortcut, value is changing but not slider.

Comment: @user17502017 `slider.setValue()` should do the trick, given that you're targeting the right `QSlider`. Are you sure the keyshortcut is being triggered? If you print something on the triggered callback, the print really appears on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, the value has changed and it appears in terminal but, the changed value is not setting here. P.S: the value is changing but slider is not changing .

Comment: @user17502017 1. For future reference, try to improve your explanations (if you have difficulties with English, try to find someone that can help you), as until now it was extremely unclear to what "*value*" you were referring to, and a "model" has absolutely nothing to do with the layout. 2. Make `Params` a QObject subclass, add a custom signal and emit it when the value changes.

Comment: @musicamante updated my question now, sorry  for the ambiguous question. I am completely new to pyqt5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through threading.

There is an exact procedure to achieve threading using PyQt5.
If you are not following it correctly, the application will crash without any error messages.

You will need the `QThread` lib and create workers to overwrite `run` method of QThread.

Here some link describing this:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ffF0U36b0
- https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/#using-qthread-to-prevent-freezing-guis

Here is the code with buttons:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
class Worker(QObject):  # Step 1: Create a worker class
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        for i in range(5):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i + 1)
        self.finished.emit()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    # Snip...
    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()

        # Final resets
        self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(True)
        )
        self.thread.finished.connect(
            lambda: self.stepLabel.setText("Long-Running Step: 0")
        )
```

Comment: Multithreading is only needed if you want to create something more complex that visually changes over time, such as a *smooth effect* (just like scrolling the page down with the mouse). If the OP wants to increase a slider by a raw value, such as *+1* or *+10*, where visual processing over time is not needed, multithreading is not really needed. It can be used but it's unnecessary, a simple function does the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didnt mean this. My application is running smoothly but I want to move qslider position depending on the value change. Current pyqt5 has slider.valuechanged.connect() function triggeres if slider is dragged to right or left. But I want to move slider by itself by changing its value (not manually) it should trigger itself when value is changed.

Comment: @CarlHR Be very carefull with theses affirmations! Indeed if you are not using multiprocessing but simple thread, if two threads acces the graphic object to modify it at the same time, it will crash the QT app without error messages! I spend more than 3 months to find it to increase my app stability.

Comment: @user17502017 during computation the pyqt5 app is freeze, the only stable way is to use multiprocessing and deport your computation into it to free the graphical app (no freezed).

Answer (score 1):

Using PySide2 (which is basically the same as PyQt5), I created this minor example. It displays a single `QSlider`. If you press `Ctrl+W` or `Ctrl+S`, the `QShortcut` is activated and it respectively increases or decreases the `QSlider` by +1 or -1.

Here's the script:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSlider, QShortcut
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence

class Scene(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.slider = QSlider()
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.slider.setMinimum(4)
        self.slider.setMaximum(8)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.scene = Scene()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scene)
        self.shortcutUp = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+W'), self)
        self.shortcutDw = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+S'), self)

        self.shortcutUp.activated.connect(self.up)
        self.shortcutDw.activated.connect(self.down)

    def up(self):
        print('up')
        self.scene.slider.setValue(self.scene.slider.value()+1)

    def down(self):
        print('down')
        self.scene.slider.setValue(self.scene.slider.value()-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

I used a `QShortcut` so I didn't have to create a menubar, and set a shortcut there. It makes the exmaple smaller but with the same behaviour.

Comment: please have a look at the updated code. I have a dummy class. Let me know, how to do it?

Comment: updated my question it's more clear now. Please have a look